# Synapse Analytics - Zip files with CETAS

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I would like to know if it is possible to use serverless SQL CETAS to zip files. Especially zipping csv-file(s).

I know the integration pipelines can do it. I would like to handle as much possible through serverless sql. If not I will of course use the pipelines.